# Why is `sed '$d' file` not deleting lastlines?

Tags: bash, sed, file-management

### Where to begin to diagnose the problem?

I don't even know where to begin to look.  I'm practicing string and file wrangling, and I cannot get `sed '$d' file.sh` to delete the last line of a file; furthermore, I tried using sudo (also this did not work).

### My source says my command should work.

I know that you can use things like `cat`, `tail`, and `head -n -1` to print, and I also read that I should be able to use these to delete, but the only reliable source I've found that talks about literally removing lines is here: https://linuxhint.com/sed-command-to-delete-a-line/ and it says to use the command shown above: **it doesn't work**.

### Best guess?

I've noticed that the command succeeds with `-i` to delete the last line of the file.  Why does -i work and the lack of -i not work?  What is happening behind the scenes when I do not include -i, and will it destroy my harddrive?

Comment: `sed -i` will edit the file in place (making a backup of the current file if you specify it). See `sed --help` or `man sed` to more information. If you just use `sed` without `-i` that will produce the output to the **stdout**

Comment: @EdgarMagallon -i is actually not mentioned in man sed (at least not in Debian).

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 [of course it is](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/sed/sed.1.en.html): "-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

    edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied) "

Comment: @muru Thanks.  Edgar also said that.  Thanks, Edgar.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 what muru meant is that actually `-i` is mentioned in `man sed`. The link provided is the sed manual for Debian (check the link). It's weird if you do not have that option in your man. Maybe you have an old (or outdated) Debian installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` (a command from the 70s) is a `s`tream `ed`itor, it's not meant to edit files. See `ed`, `ex`, `vi` for file text editors.

`sed` takes a stream on input either stdin or the contents of files if some are passed as arguments, processes them on the fly applying the commands in the `sed` script for each line matching the address(es) and prints the result of that filtering on standard output.

So `sed '$d'` prints all the input except the last line (`$`) which is `d`iscarded / `d`eleted.

You can save that output to a file by adding `> newfile` or pipe it along to another command like `| tr -s '[:blank:]' ' '` to squeeze blanks.

`perl` (from the mid-80s) has a `-p` option that makes it work like `sed`. `perl` also added a `-i[.back]` (for `i`n-place) option that changes the behaviour so that instead of writing the result on stdout, it writes it into a new copy of the file, optionally keeping the original copy with a `.back` suffix.

Both The GNU and FreeBSD implementations of `sed` added a similar feature in the early 2000s though with different syntax for when no backup is required: `sed -i '$d' file` with GNU's and `sed -i '' '$d' file` with FreeBSD's.  `sed -i.back '$d'` works in both, `sed -i .back '$d'` only in FreeBSD's.

Several other `sed` implementations have added a `-i` option since, most of them the GNU way, but not all and in any case, that's not a standard option.

`sed` is not the only stream editor application. `cat`, `awk`, `paste`, `tr`, `nroff`, `eq`, `sort`, `join`, `cut`... work the same way and take input and produce output. The idea is that you pipe them together to achieve some task, one of the strength of Unix shell scripting. Few others of those can edit a file in place. The GNU implementation of `awk` aka `gawk` has a `-i in-place` option. `sort` can be called with `sort -o file file` (it can because it needs to read the whole input before starting to write the output, there's no backup in that case).

Comment: Interesting reading.  I am a little confused.  I wish you'd break your paragraphs by tone and lesson point.  Do cat/paste/tr/nroff/eq/sort/join/cut have -i options?  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html cat seems to not.

Comment: I'd like to dig deeper.  Any inclination about why the article by LinuxHint (in question) Says nothing about -i?  "Sed Command to Delete a Line", 2021, https://linuxhint.com/sed-command-to-delete-a-line/